# Can I debug TypeScript file in blank Node.js Console Application using Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I am using `Visual Studio 2015` to create a `Blank Node.js Console Application`.  The application create a simple Hello World `TypeScript` file (`app.ts`):

```
console.log('Hello world');
```

i try to set a break point to the `app.ts` file and run with debugging.  Apparently, the debugger doesn't stop at the break point.  The sourcemap option is on.

Can I debug a console TypeScript application using Visual Studio?